# How call Screenshot method after each Selenium action

Tags: c#, selenium, specflow

I work with Specflow (if there is such a function there)
Programming language C#.

I want a screenshot to be taken after each selenium action.
Why? -> I want that after the first automation, a series of pictures of the successful test run is created (so that business analysts in the future can quickly see via pictures, what is tested with which test caseid).
It should be possible to specify via a flag whether the screenshot should be created or not. So my main problem is:
How do I ensure that my screenshot function is automatically called after each "driver.FindElement.... "and then "variable.click" or similar?
I don't want to manually insert "makeScreenshot()" everywhere.
It would be wonderful if a different method could be called after each method call. That looks up what the "command is". If the syntax then matches something like "Click()", the screenshot is triggered, otherwise not.
If there is no such thing. Something like "Screenshot(variable.Click())" would also be conceivable. That would still be clean and easily implemented everywhere via copy paste.

Does anyone have an idea or a link? (I'm a bit of a noob and need code examples to get started)

Comment: I can think of a way to do this. You can implement your own versions of IWebDriver and IWebElement that take screenshots.

Comment: I don't think there is a good general solution. Beware the clicking an element might seem fast to you, but if it triggers some fade-in effect, you might take a screenshot too quickly.

Comment: How would you name the files?

Answer (score 0):

**Potential solution 1:**
You could add a [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) to your project for IWebElement, which would allow you to create your own custom click and find methods that screenshot after clicking. For example:

```
    public static class IWebElementExtensions
    {
        public static void ClickAndScreenshot(this IWebElement element,
           IWebDriver driver,
           ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
        {
            element.Click();

            Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
            ss.SaveAsFile($"{scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title}_{scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text.Replace("\"", "")}.png",
            ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
```

If you add the above class to your project and reference it in your steps, it would click the element, and then take a screenshot and add the scenario and step info to the filename to identify it later (consider how you plan to manage these screenshots, might be worth adding a subfolder per scenario, or datetimes to the filename for diagnostics).

You can then make use of this method in your Specflow steps:

```
        [When(@"I click a login button")]
        public void WhenIClickALoginButton()
        {
            By someLoginButton = By.Id("login");

            _driver.FindElement(someLoginButton).ClickAndScreenshot(_driver, _scenarioContext);
        }
```

You could do something similar for finding the element. You could create an extension method that finds the element, takes a screenshot and then returns the element as a return type to be used by your WebDriver.

You would have to change your current click() methods to take advantage of this new method (find and replace should help make this trivial), but your screenshot code would all be in one place if you need to change it. Doing it this way means you can pick and choose when to call that method as well depending on your steps, as you could stick to the original Click() method if not interested in a screenshot in a particular step.

**Potential Solution 2:**

I feel like taking a screenshot after every Specflow step rather then each Selenium action is worth mentioning as a potential solution, focusing on chunks of user actions rather then every Selenium action.

For example, you could configure a hooks file to take a screenshot after every specflow step:

```
    [Binding]
    public class Hooks
    {
        IWebDriver _driver;

        public Hooks(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            _driver = driver;
        }

        [Scope(Tag = "screenshot")]
        [AfterStep]
        public void TakeScreenshotAfterStep(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
        {
            Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)_driver).GetScreenshot();
            screenshot.SaveAsFile($"{scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Title}_{scenarioContext.StepContext.StepInfo.Text}.png",
            ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
        }

        [AfterScenario]
        public void AfterScenario()
        {
            _driver.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

For a example Feature:

```
Feature: Login

@screenshot
Scenario: Successful Login
GIVEN I navigate to stack overflow
WHEN I login
THEN I am logged in

@someOtherTag
Scenario: API test with no UI
GIVEN I have a cool API
WHEN I do a GET
THEN I GET some cool stuff
```

This would generate 3 screenshots after each step for the Successful login scenario, but it wouldn't take any for the API test due to the tag scope on the after step, which should tick the box around being able to specify when to do this.

The above relies on your Specflow steps not being too large though... if you're doing multiple large chunks of user actions within one step, it may skip a lot, but if that's only a rare occurrence you could do some extra screenshot taking within those steps using the extension from potential solution 1.

I hope this helps, I apprieciate it's not a pure answer but from experience of when these sorts of screenshots can be useful, I'd recommend solution 2 and use it as an opportunity to make sure your Specflow steps aren't doing too much.